# Proving technique for exchanging lim and (infinite) sum where the sum converges very slowly.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, laplace-transform

I have the following function $f(x)$ given a pair of positive real parameter $s$ and $t$:

\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= 1,   \text{if $-max(s,t)<x<0$};\\ 
f(0) &= 1.5; \\ 
f(x) &= f(x-s)+f(x-t),  \text{if $x > 0$}.
\end{aligned}

I have explored some properties of this function (with some not-so-strict proof that I'll omit here):

- $f(x)$ grows exponentially
- $f(x) = 1 + \sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\frac{(p+q)!}{p!q!}u(x - (ps+qt))$, where $u(x)$ is the [unit step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) with $u(0) = 0.5$
- (obtained using Laplace transform) $f(x) = \sum_{r}\frac{e^{rx}}{r(se^{-sr}+te^{-tr})}$, where $r$ are all the complex roots of equation $e^{-sr}+e^{-tr} = 1$. The summation order is using $r$ that's closer to the origin first.

In the third bullet point, the equation $e^{-sr}+e^{-tr} = 1$ always has a single positive real root, which I call $r = R$. I want to show that its corresponding term is the "dominant term" of the function. That is, if we define
$$
F(x) = \frac{e^{Rx}}{R(se^{-sR}+te^{-tR})}
$$
I want to show the limit
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{F(x)} = 1
$$
which is equivalent to showing that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{r\neq R}\frac{e^{(r-R)x}}{r(se^{-sr}+te^{-tr})} = 0
$$

I actually discovered that this isn't always true. In particular, whenever $s/t\in\mathbb{Q}$, this limit doesn't exist, as it oscillates forever. What I haven't fully understand is the $s/t\notin\mathbb{Q}$ case, for which I suspect that the limit does exist.

I noticed that when $s/t\notin\mathbb{Q}$, $R$ has the single largest real components among all roots, so each individual term $e^{(r-R)x}$ has a limit of 0. I wish I could exchange the limit and summation operators to prove that the sum also has a limit of 0, but I can't find a theorem to back it up. [Tannery's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem) doesn't work, as the sum isn't even absolute convergent (hence there is no hope for me to find the bound that appears in the theorem).

So my question is: is there any tools I can use here to exchange the limit operator, or is there a different ways to find the limit using $f$'s other properties? Or maybe the limit actually doesn't exist, and if so, is there a way to show it?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a tricky solution for the specific problem.

First let's introduce a smooth version of the unit jump function
$$
u_a(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &\quad (x < 0)\\
x/a &\quad (0\le x \le a)\\
1 &\quad (x > a)\\
\end{cases}
$$
And use it to construct a smooth version of $f(x)$:
$$
f_a(x) = 1 + \sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\frac{(p+q)!}{p!q!}u_a(x-(ps+qt)) = \sum_r\frac{(1-e^{-ar})e^{rx}}{ar^2(se^{-sr}+ts^{-tr})}
$$
which luckily converges absolutely (because this is a $\sum 1/n^2$-like series, which is because roots $r$ has almost periodic layout, which is intuitive to see but tedious to prove), and we can find bounds to apply Tannery's theorem. The limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f_a(x)}{F(x)} = \frac{1-e^{-aR}}{aR}
$$

At the same time, we have
$$
u_a(x)\le u(x) \le u_a(x+a)
$$
which means
$$
f_a(x)\le f(x) \le f_a(x+a)
$$
and then their limit
$$
\frac{1-e^{-aR}}{aR}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f_a(x)}{F(x)}\le \liminf_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{F(x)}\le \limsup_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{F(x)} \le \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f_a(x+a)}{F(x)}=\frac{e^{aR}-1}{aR}
$$
By choosing arbitrarily small $a$, we squeeze the limit
$$
1\le \liminf_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{F(x)}\le \limsup_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{F(x)}\le1
$$

So I guess the takeaway from this is that, if the series you want to exchange limit and sum doesn't work well, try looking at its neighbors.